# Ajax request returns bad request error code

Tags: json, ajax, flask

I am getting a bad request response to my request. I have checked with an online JSON validator my dictionary data to be correct, and everything seems fine.

My code is the following:

```
// Parse datetime to timestamp and include data in a dict
        let data_dict = {
            "stop_date": Date.parse(sup_limit.value),
            "start_date": Date.parse(inf_limit.value)
        }
        // Send the Ajax request
        let request = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data_dict,
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        });
```

Backend receive endpoint:

```
@dashboard_bp.route('/download_last_test_influx<mode>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def download_last_test_influx(mode: str):
    # Check if request comes from a custom or test event
    if mode == 'custom':
        start_date = int(request.json.get('start_date'))
        stop_date = int(request.json.get('stop_date'))
        # Check if time range is valid, if not return server internal error
        if stop_date - start_date <= 0:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Time range must be grater than 0'}), 500
    # Create response header
    response = make_response(send_file(spock_comm_mgr
                                       .test_backup_influx_manager
                                       .get_last_test_influx_record(start_date=start_date, stop_date=stop_date)))
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/gzip'
    response.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
    return response
```

**Request header:**

```
POST /download_last_test_influxcustom HTTP/1.1
Host: 0.0.0.0:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 48
Origin: http://0.0.0.0:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://0.0.0.0:5000/influx_management
Cookie: *********************
```

**Request payload:**

```
stop_date=1623758400000&start_date=1623708000000
```

**Response message:**

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Comment: Even if the sent data is valid json (use the developer tools to check what is REALLY sent to the server), the API may expect different properties ... is there any error message in the response, except status code 400?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @derpirscher! I have included the header and payload of the request, and the response message. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling your server, you are sending JSON data, but the request body is not a JSON string but a url-encoded string (because that's the default behaviour of `$.ajax()` when you pass an object as `data`).

Use `JSON.stringify`, to pass a correct JSON body

```
let request = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(data_dict),
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    });
```